# TYPO3 felogin - How to set preserveGETvars or redirect_url to actual page via Hook?

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-10.x, felogin

**TYPO3: v10.4.2**

**My issue:**
I've a LoginForm in my template that is visible in the menue. I just want to be able to login wherever the user is and reload the same page.
That works quite fine with normal pages...
BUT! When we are in a NewsItem or another detail-side of any extension, it doesn't take the parameters which are mandatory to reload the same page. What leads into a `Required argument "news" is not set for...`

I tried to get the parameters somehow to felogin - there's that `preserveGETvars` - but that doesn't do anything. No idea how that works.

And my other idea was to give felogin the total uri of the actual page to redirect. There's a hook mentioned in the documentary but I have no clue about using hooks. :/

Why is it so hard to configure. I just want the ext to login and open the same page again. Isn't that quite common? :((

I hope somebody can help me.

Setup-Config:
I saw that and tried it but there's no effect.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  settings {
    redirectMode = getpost
    preserveGETvars = tx_news[news],tx_news_pi1[news]
  }

  view {
    templateRootPaths.2 = fileadmin/templates/felogin/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.2 = fileadmin/templates/felogin/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.2 = fileadmin/templates/felogin/Layouts/
  }
}
```

And I tried lot's of preserveGETvars also **all**

The documentation says preserveGETvars = **tx_ttnews[tt_news]**,tx_myext[id],... - but that seams to be really old. and I tried it, doesn't work at all. :/

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/master/en-us//Configuration/Index.html?highlight=preservegetvars Did you make a typoscript condition for the news pages and add the get params of it at preserveGETvars? You can see at the examples for the routeEnhancers which params you need. Show us your code. I can explain how to write a hook, but it seems it's not needed in this case.

Comment: sorry, just added the code.

Comment: I tried to find out what the ext tries to do and found out that preserveGETvars is just used in the FrontendLoginController but it seams that it never reaches that. Was there a change with Typo3v10 and that doesn't work anymore?

Comment: It's still there https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/Controller/FrontendLoginController.php line 1007. Did you turn off cache and routeEnhancer to test?

Comment: It's there - that's right, but it looks like it's not called at all by the loginAction in the LoginController that's used by the Fluid Form. I think FrontendLoginController is just used by the pi-plugin but that's not used anymore in Typo3 v10.4

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the routeEnhancer off you can see the GET parameters in the URL. For NEWS detail it could be

```
 tx_news_pi1[action],tx_news_pi1[controller],tx_news_pi1[news]
```

I also would make a condition to apply this only on the detail page.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work. I tried to switch of routeEnhancer but it's the same problem. shouldn't i see a change in the source code? what should happen? I guess the arguments should be as well in the form-action-url, right? there's no change at all.

Comment: ... and - I don't wanna switch off the routeEnhancer. Is it really true that it doesn't work at all with normal url-segments?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a way with felogin and 10LTS. So i just switched to the old mode, Settings > Configure Installation-Wide Options:

```
[SYS][features][felogin.extbase] = false
```

I had to insert the plugin again, but then it worked instantly, without "preserveGETvars" or anything. Not the solution i want but at least it works now.

Comment: The point is the pi1 plugin will be removed in one of the next versions. That's why I didn't try that. That's not a solution if I have the same problem with the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Very late, but my solution was simply to url encode the ? and & signs

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but since the problem persists in TYPO3 v11.5 and other people might stumble upon this post.

The problem lies within the `<f:form />` in the Fluid-Template and it not propagating the Queries of whatever detailpage we're currently on. Adding  `addQueryString="true"` to the `f:form` has solved that problem for me.
Now the URL of the action for the form on submit is correct and therefore the form itself redirects properly.

I really hope this saves someone else the nearly 3 hours of trial and error I just did.